# Take if there is an integer part as the tail of a string variable in PHP

Tags: php, string, integer, string-conversion

How to extract the integer part(the last integer) of a string variable to another integer variable in PHP.

Here is the current status of my code:

```
<?php
 $path = current_path(); // eg. loading 'node/43562' to $path
 $pos = strpos($path, 'node/');
 if($pos>-1)die(print $pos); // sometimes $pos can be 0, may be 5 or even 26..like so
 ...
?>
```

All I need is to get the integer part comes after `'node/'` out from `$path` only if the integer is the last thing in the `$part`.

Do nothing if `$path` is:

- *'greenpage/12432/node'*, or
- *'56372/page/2321'*, or
- *'node/56372/page'*.

I don't want to go through lengthy codes like:

```
<?php
 $arr = explode(":",$path);
 $a= $arr[1];
 $b= $arr[3];
 $c= $arr[5];
 ...
 ...
?>
```

I have to use this **43562** in many places.
Hope it can be implemented with any simple `preg_` methods, or a complex regex.

**Waiting for the minimal LOC solution.**

Comment: http://www.writemycodeforme.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to the number in a myriad of ways.

Here is a simple regex:

```
preg_match('/\d+$/', $path, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

If it is important to check that the prefix is also there then:

```
preg_match('/(?<=node\/)\d+$/', $path, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

You can also use `strrpos()` and `substr()`:

```
$slash = strrpos($path, '/');
if ($slash !== false) {
    echo substr($path, $slash + 1);
}
```

It is also possible to just chop up the string. It is a little quick'n'dirty, but it works:

```
$parts = explode('/', $path);
echo array_pop($parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "foo/bar/node/1234";

if(preg_match('/node\/([0-9]+)$/', $string, $match)) {

        echo $match[1];
}
```

Comment: You mean `$match[1]`, don't you?